# Why does my graph sometimes use different data source when calling it?

Tags: excel, vba, graph, pivot-table

I am currently developing code that sorts and creates reports over sorted data in vba. The sorted data is placed in its on excel sheet based on certain criteria and then two pivot tables are made from data and two graphs are made using the pivot tables. The pivot tables and one graph are working as intended but one of my graphs will sometimes show the same data as the other even though I am not changing the data source. I have also provided two screenshots of incorrect and correct graphs. Note that these two graphs were obtained by running the same code multiple times in a row without any change.

Incorrect graph

[image]

Correct graph

[image]

```
    Sub IPReport()

    Dim PTCache As PivotCache, PT As PivotTable, LRow As Integer, LCol As Integer, sum As Single

    Sheets("IP").Activate

    LRow = Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row
    LCol = Range("XFD1").End(xlToLeft).Column
    LRowP = Range("V1").End(xlDown).Row

    Set Size = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LRow, 10))
    Set PTCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=Size)
    
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
   'deleting graphs if they already exist

    If LRow >= 3 Then
    
       Dim wsWorksheet As Worksheet
       Set wsWorksheet = Worksheets("IP")
       On Error Resume Next
       wsWorksheet.PivotTables("Data").TableRange2.Clear
       wsWorksheet.PivotTables("1Shift").TableRange2.Clear
       'statement that deletes pivot tables that already exsist
    
       Set PT = ActiveSheet.PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=PTCache, TableDestination:=Range("L1"),  TableName:="Data")   
       Worksheets("IP").PivotTables(1).AddFields ColumnFields:=Array("Shift"), RowFields:=Array("Part Desc")
       ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Data").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Data").PivotFields("Total $"), "$ for part", xlSum
       With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Data").PivotFields("$ for part")
        .NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"
       End With
       '$ pivot table
    
    Set PT = ActiveSheet.PivotTables.Add(PivotCache:=PTCache, TableDestination:=Range("V1"), TableName:="1Shift")
    Worksheets("IP").PivotTables(1).AddFields ColumnFields:=Array("Shift"), RowFields:=Array("Part Desc")
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("1Shift").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables("1Shift").PivotFields("Quantity"), "Part Quantities", xlSum
    'Quantity pivot table

Dim LRowd As Integer
Dim QChart As ChartObject
    
    LRow = Range("V1").End(xlDown).Row
    LRowM = Range("L1").End(xlDown).Row
    
    Set QChart = Sheets("IP").ChartObjects.Add(Left:=682, Width:=600, Top:=700, Height:=400)
        **QChart.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("IP").Range(Cells(3, 22), Cells(LRow - 1, 25))**
        QChart.Chart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
        QChart.Chart.SetElement (msoElementChartTitleAboveChart)
        QChart.Chart.ChartTitle.Text = "Total Amount of Defects"
        QChart.Chart.SetElement msoElementDataLabelShow
'creating column chart
    
Else: MsgBox ("Insufficient data for report")
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: `On Error Resume Next` will hide any problems with your code, and make it impossible to debug.

Comment: Thank you, I added an On Error GoTo 0 and got an error with source data for the chart. Do you know why that could happen?

Comment: Please update your post with your current code, and tell us which line gave you the error, and what the text of the error message is.

Comment: If the line with the asterisks is the problem line, try changing it to `QChart.Chart.SetSourceData Source:=Sheets("IP").Range(Sheets("IP").Cells(3, 22), Sheets("IP").Cells(LRow - 1, 25))`

Comment: Tried this but it is still having the same issue

Comment: In which Sheet runs this code, what's the name of the sheet?

Comment: The sheet it is run in is called "IP"